# Image Processing Microprocessor selection

Tags: image-processing, communication, microprocessors

I m new to **image processing**, but i need know which **Microprocessor** is very useful for image processing. Which Board can process do image processing faster and also communicate to ground station i.e good and long range **communication** facility like wifi,.. .After searching a lot of processors, i come to conclusion **Beaglebone and Cubietruck**. I know **c and c++**. Can you people suggest which one is good Beaglebone or Cubietruck. i m bit confused with 2 specifications. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably ask this on Electrical Engineering StackExchange: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ .  This is also a very broad and primarily opinion-based question.  Those kinds of questions are not suitable here on StackOverflow as it would bring answers that are subject to debate and we all can't agree on one answer.  Voting to close.

Comment: I agree this is not about programing and also opinion based so (+close) here. If you migrate this then do not forget to include details like what kind of image processing, resolution, fps,... and also you wrote you are confused with 2 specifications which ones ? only with more details you can chose between SISD/SIMD/MIMD NeuralNet or DSP or hybrid ... and then selecting the board ...